# Obtaining x-axis values in c3.js to customize the tooltip?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I'm trying to edit the tooltip in a c3 line-chart.  Specifically, I need to access the current x-value within the `chart.tooltip.format.value` function.  However, the function is not passed the x-value explicitly.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    tooltip: {
        format: {
            value: function (value, ratio, id, index) {
                return value;
            }
        }
    },

    data: {
        x: 'YEAR',
        xFormat: '%Y',
        url: myURL',
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%Y'
            }
        },
    },

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the tooltip's `contents` property to create a custom tooltip, and in there you can access the X value via: `d[0].x`.

**Edit:  use `d[0].x.getFullYear()` to retrieve only the year part of the date** (it's a time series so C3 internally stores the supplied year as a javascript date object)

Here's code I've taken from this discussion https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/444, and modified:

```
function tooltip_contents(d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
    var $$ = this, config = $$.config, CLASS = $$.CLASS,
        titleFormat = config.tooltip_format_title || defaultTitleFormat,
        nameFormat = config.tooltip_format_name || function (name) { return name; },
        valueFormat = config.tooltip_format_value || defaultValueFormat,
        text, i, title, value, name, bgcolor;

    // You can access all of data like this:
    //console.log($$.data.targets);

    for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        if (! (d[i] && (d[i].value || d[i].value === 0))) { continue; }

        // to exclude
        //if (d[i].name === 'data2') { continue; }

        if (! text) {
            title = 'MY TOOLTIP @ ' + d[0].x.getFullYear(); // SHOW X-VALUE, year only (given it is a time series)
            text = "<table class='" + CLASS.tooltip + "'>" + (title || title === 0 ? "<tr><th colspan='2'>" + title + "</th></tr>" : "");
        }

        name = nameFormat(d[i].name);
        value = valueFormat(d[i].value, d[i].ratio, d[i].id, d[i].index);
        bgcolor = $$.levelColor ? $$.levelColor(d[i].value) : color(d[i].id);

        text += "<tr class='" + CLASS.tooltipName + "-" + d[i].id + "'>";
        text += "<td class='name'><span style='background-color:" + bgcolor + "'></span>" + name + "</td>";
        text += "<td class='value'>" + value + "</td>";
        text += "</tr>";            
    }

    return text + "</table>";    
}

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'year',
        xFormat: '%Y',
        columns: [
            ['year', '1970', '1975', '1980', '1985', '1990'],
            ['data1', 100, 200, 150, 300, 200],
            ['data2', 400, 500, 250, 700, 300],
        ]
    },
       axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%Y'
            }
        },
    },

    tooltip: {
        contents: tooltip_contents
    }
});
```

My fiddle, showing the current x-value: http://jsfiddle.net/w7h385h3/5/

Comment: Thanks for the code.  However, the x-values (which are loaded from a csv), are years, for example `1970`.  But  the value within `d[i].x` are formatted as `Thur Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)`

Comment: Without overriding the tooltip properties, the title appears correctly as `1970`

Comment: That's because you specify `xFormat: '%Y'` which returns only the year. It applies this internally. I've updated the code with the time series and javascript date objects, and display just the year - http://jsfiddle.net/w7h385h3/4/

Comment: As long as you're passing the years in as strings it still works: `['year', '1970', '1975', '1980', '1985', '1990']`